# How do I restore lost Garageband instruments?

Tags: garageband, logic

I opened Garageband after a long time and noticed that all my instruments are lost. The .exs and sampler files are still where they are supposed to be: `/Library/Application Support/Garageband/Instrument Library` but Garageband isn't detecting them. I can't afford to download 6 GB's worth of instruments.

How do I make Garageband detect them?

I also have Logic Pro installed.